# SELECT rows from Table1 having identical values on columns and Table2 Column > N

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

This is simple. I have two tables. I need to select rows from Table1 which have same 'Customer' and in Table2 'yearmm' is bigger than 2015001.

Table1

```
id  |  Customer  |   yearmmm  |  
----------------------------
10  |   123456   |   2015001  |
11  |   456789   |   2015001  |
20  |   111111   |   2015001  |
21  |   222222   |   2015001  |
44  |   4444     |   2015001  |
```

Table2

```
 id  |  Customer  |   yearmmm  |  
----------------------------
10  |   123456   |   2015001   |
11  |   456789   |   2015002   |
20  |   111111   |   2015003   |
21  |   222222   |   2010001   |
333 |   333      |   2015004   |
```

Wonder if this works:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Customer IN 
(SELECT Customer FROM Table2 WHERE yearmmm  > '2015001')
```

Desired result:

```
11  |   456789   |   2015002   |
20  |   111111   |   2015003   |
```

Comment: is `yearmmm` a datetime or date  or a varchar column?

Comment: This will not work. At least you dont connect `Customer` in two tables.

Comment: What date is `2015001`? Also, `Table1` does not contain records with `yearmmm` IN (2015002, 2015003), so why do you exptect them as result when you want to select from `Table1`? Poor sample data because all t1-customers are in t2 and all dates in t2 are bigger than 20150101.

Comment: yearmmm is `int` not a date.

Comment: I need to compare these tables, need to get rows from `Table1` where there's `yearmmm` > 2015001 in 'Table2'.

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov  Damn, I already used this for a while. Results seemed to be ok. But, if this doesn't work, what do you suggest?

Comment: If your tables are exactly like that see answer of @Tom. Your example is little misleading because you have 2 tables with the same structure. In that case you can ommit one of the tables. But I assume that you have other columns which you are not posted here (to avoid too long examples). In that case you need to connect `Customer` from `Table 1` with `Customer` from `Table 2`. I think you should takle into account comment of @Tim Schmelter. In general - EDIT your question - it is not very clear.

Comment: Also if you use this and it works where is the question :) ? I mean what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Edited question. I just need to make sure my query does what I think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2
   WHERE t1.Customer = t2.Customer
   AND   t2.yearmmm  > '20150101'
)
```

You have other options like `INNER JOIN` or `IN`.

Comment: This works. Funny that my query gave exactly the same result. Maybe it works as I thought.

Answer (score 1):

Well, no, that will not work. You're ultimately selecting the Customer and yearmmm from Table1 based on values in Table2. Yet your desired results show yearmmm values that exist in Table2.

Based on your desired results it seems like you just want this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE yearmmm > '2015001'
```

**EDIT**: If you do in fact need more data from Table1, consider:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.Customer, t2.yearmmm, another_other_fields 
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.yearmmm > '2015001'
```

Comment: Good solution! If this is the structure - he does not need fisrt table. But if he has more fields, he will need 1st table anyway.

Comment: Edited question, had poor sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT 
  t1.*
FROM 
  Table1 t1 
  INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON 
    (t1.Customer = t2.Customer)
    AND (t2.yearmmm  > '2015001');
```

Or

```
SELECT 
  t1.*
FROM 
  Table1 t1 
  INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON 
    (t1.Customer = t2.Customer)
WHERE 
  (t2.yearmmm  > '2015001');
```